# How do I chunk the records in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, text-manipulation

lets say i have a column Name in tableA

```
Name
jennifer Hughs
Mike nadrotosky
Arnold Woods
Raj Jai Soni
```

so how do i put these results in seperate 3 columns  like

```
FirstName MiddleName LastName
Jennifer              Hughs
.
.
.
Raj        Jai       Soni
```

I tried with Substring but not working.

Comment: And what happens if somebody's name is Raj Jai Mai Soni?

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanks thats a good question. in that case Mai Soni will go in LastName. Here i have something but dont know if that would help..     select top 1 name , substring(name, 1, 6) as firstname,
              substring(name, 6, 2) as LastName,
              substring(name, 8, 2) as LastName
from #TEMP

Comment: What happens if someone's name is Billy Bob Earnest Jones where Jones is the last name, Earnest is the middle name and Billy Bob is the first name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it looks at lot easier than it really is - especially if you start having people with multiple first- and/or middle names.

My approach would be to create a stored function that encapsulates that logic - it's really not that simple to just spell it out in an inline T-SQL statement.

Here's a first attempt - works as long as you don't have more than a single middle name:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitName(@InputName VARCHAR(200))
RETURNS @nameParts TABLE 
(
    FirstName VARCHAR(100),
    MiddleName VARCHAR(100),
    LastName VARCHAR(100)
)
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @FirstSpace INT, @LastSpace INT

    SET @FirstSpace = CHARINDEX(' ', @InputName)
    SET @LastSpace = CHARINDEX(' ', @InputName, @FirstSpace+1)

    INSERT INTO @nameParts(FirstName, MiddleName, LastName)
        SELECT
            SUBSTRING(@InputName, 1, @FirstSpace),
            CASE @LastSpace 
                WHEN 0 THEN CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(100))
                ELSE SUBSTRING(@InputName, @FirstSpace+1, @LastSpace - @FirstSpace)
            END,
            CASE @LastSpace 
                WHEN 0 THEN SUBSTRING(@InputName, @FirstSpace+1, 999)
                ELSE SUBSTRING(@InputName, @LastSpace, 999)
            END

    RETURN
END
```

If you test this with some sample data, you'll get the following results:

```
DECLARE @nameTable TABLE (NameValue VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @nametable VALUES('Jennifer Hughes')
INSERT INTO @nametable VALUES('Mike Nadrotosky')
INSERT INTO @nametable VALUES('Arnold Woods')
INSERT INTO @nametable VALUES('Raj Jai Soni')

SELECT *
FROM @nameTable
CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitName(nameValue)
```

and the output for that SELECT is:

```
NameValue          FirstName   MiddleName    LastName
Jennifer Hughes    Jennifer       NULL       Hughes
Mike Nadrotosky    Mike           NULL       Nadrotosky
Arnold Woods       Arnold         NULL       Woods
Raj Jai Soni       Raj            Jai        Soni
```

Comment: I like your approach on this. If you want to use it to fetch multiple middle names (the rule is first + middle + middle + ... + last) you could reverse the string and substring to get last name using reverse charindex, then put that in last, first in first, and rest in middle.

Comment: Hi @marc_s thanks for your help. but if i run your query, it gives error : The select list for the INSERT statement contains fewer items than the insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns.
i dont know whats wrong..

Comment: @Programmer: sorry, I had some test variables in my table to get this to work - I've updated my answer, this should work now, I hope!

Comment: Yes i got it. Really appreciate your help. just a curious question if i just want the first letter in LastName column(H, N, W, S) how do i do it? Thanks

Comment: @Programmer: `SUBSTRING(LastName, 1, 1)`

Answer (score 0):

@marc_s answer is the most complete.  The few times I've had to do this they've been as one-off data load type jobs.  If yours is the same I would strongly suggest just doing it in Excel!

1. Copy and paste the table from Management studio in to Excel
2. Use text to columns
3. Re-sort the whole row on column 3 to get all of those with no middle name at the top
4. Select all of the ones with an empty column 3 and move the values from Column 2 in to column 3
5. Import the data in to the destination SQL Table

For doing this in T-SQL I have done it using the string split function in [SQL Sharp](http://www.sqlsharp.com/).  This will however ultimately yield similar results to @marc_s so I won't go in to it here.